# Retrieving Imgur Image Link via Web Scraping Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve the link for an image using imgur.com. It seems that the picture (if .jpg or .png) is usually stored within (div class="image post-image") on their website, like:

```html
<div class='image post-image'>
    <img alt="" src="//i.imgur.com/QSGvOm3.jpg" original-title="" style="max-width: 100%; min-height: 666px;">
</div>
```

so here is my code so far:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://imgur.com/gallery/0PTPt'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
info = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'post-image'})

file = open('imgur-html.txt', 'w')
file.write(str(info))
file.close()
```

Instead of being able to get everything within these tags, this is my output:

```html
<div class="post-image" style="min-height: 666px">
</div>
```

What do I need to do in order to access this further so I can get the image link? Or is this simply something where I need to only use the API? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child img it would appear is dynamically added and not present. You can extract full link from rel

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://imgur.com/gallery/0PTPt')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('[rel=image_src]')['href'])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot for the help